# New to C++, I do not understand how to display output in a .txt file

Tags: c++, output

I am very new to C++. I have my code and it displays my desired output in a win32 console.

However, my Instructor wants the output to be run through a .txt file. We have done this before with a program that had input already written within the coding.

ex.

```
cout << "example1....example2";
```

We achieved this with his exact instructions:

*1)   Probably the easiest way to obtain a hard copy of the generated
     program output on a Microsoft Windows platform is to run your
     program from a command prompt, redirecting the output to a file.
     The command line syntax would like like this:

```
lab1prog >lab1.txt*
```

My problem, however, is that I did this again for lab2 and redirected the output to lab2.txt but I need user input for this time around. When I run the lab2.exe file, my lab2.txt file outputs my "cout" statement and waits for input but I cannot enter input through a .txt file.

Please help if you can.

Comment: you can input in almost the same way `lab1prog >lab1.txt < input.txt`

Comment: You might consider opening an ofstream and writing to it directly rather than redirecting.  The second answer here shows a simple example.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11060874/usage-of-ofstream

Comment: This is the instruction for assignment 2:
"1)   Use the method described in assignment one for obtaining the
     generated program output.
2)   You must turn in the program output using the following twelve
     input values:
       1000000   999999999     86400     60        370         90
          5400       86401    189684      1      86531     172799
"
So then would I have to make a input.txt file in order to input these values in the lab1.txt file?

Comment: It is not a "must" to have a file "input.txt". But if you want to avoid to enter the same values in each run of the program I would consider it as "useful" to have the values in a file.

Answer (score 1):

If you specifically want to use a text file as input into your program, the easiest way (as Kamil Mikolajczyk mentioned) is to run it this way:

```
> lab1prog >lab1.txt <input.txt
```

On the other hand, if you need to run the program as it is, but have complete control over what to output into the file, I'd suggest using a file handle. Check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17379390/how-to-create-ofstream-file-with-name-of-variable) on how to use file handles. You could even duplicate the output on the command prompt and the file when you want by outputting it as:

```
fout << "My output";
cout << "My output";
```

You can as well output the user input into your output file for your convenience.

Answer (score 1):

When you redirect the output of the program with

```
lab1prog >lab1.txt
```

then the user is still able to input data. The only problem is that she doesn't know *when* to enter *what* data. This is usually done by prompt outputs that are hidden whith the `>lab1.txt`.

To circumvent the problem you could abuse the error output what is not redirected with the command above.

```
cerr << "prompt";
```

To avoid this abuse you should use a "tee" program like [wintee](http://code.google.com/p/wintee/) instead of redirecting with a simple `>lab1.txt`.

If it's acceptable to get the input from a file instead from the user you can use the input redirection.

```
labprog1 <input.txt >lab1.txt
```